# SwiftUI pick custom global systemBackground color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been using the default background colors for light and dark mode, but I realized that the black color creates too much contrast in views with a lot of text.

I would like to change the default `backgroundColor` for dark mode to a slightly brighter black.

I've tried to create an extension for the `Color` struct and to overwrite the `systemBackground` color, but it didn't work.

The only solution I found is wrapping each view with the following:

```
ZStack {
    Color.myBackgroundColor.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    ...
}
```

I would really like to avoid wrapping every single view with the colored `ZStack`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Didn't try it myself, but you might want to have a look at different ways to configure the appearance attributes for views. See e.g. https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/configuring-swiftui-views/

Comment: @fishinear that article only provides a solution to change the `accentColor` i.e. the color of buttons, navigation links, etc. I need to change the `backgroundColor`.  I tried to play with `UINavigationController.view.backgroungColor`, but it didn't work properly.

Comment: They use `accentColor` as example. The general principle should be true for all attributes as far as I know.
One complication for backgroundColor is likely that it is actually set to transparent for almost all views, and you don't want to change that.